# Have array store user input and then print the largest value

Tags: java, arrays, max

I am creating a program that has the user input 5 values between 0-100 and store them in an array, so that the highest value can be printed. The problem is that after the program asks the user to input the 5 values, it does not output anything after that.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HighestGrade {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner scan =  new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Integer> scores = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int greatest = -1;



        for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter a grade (between 0 and 100): ");
            scan.nextInt();
        }

        while (scores.size()<5) {
            int input = scan.nextInt();
            if (input <= 100 && input >= 00) {
                scores.add(input);
                if(input >= greatest)
                    greatest = input;

            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Error: Make sure the grade is between 0 and 100!\nEnter a new grade!");
            }
        }

        System.out.println("\nHighest grade: "+greatest);

    }
}
```

Comment: you forgot to populate the output of the scanner into `scores` (the `for` loop)

Comment: inside the `for` loop.

Comment: How am I supposed to do that @SharonBenAsher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not storing the user inputs in an array in your `for` loop. Also in while loop, you are again asking for user inputs. So remove your for loop. Also, there is no need to store inputs in order to just find the maximum. Only one variable is enough. Here is untested code for finding maximum.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HighestGrade {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner scan =  new Scanner(System.in);
        int greatest = -1;
        int count = 0;
        while (count<5) {
            ++count;
            System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
            int input = scan.nextInt();
            if (input <= 100 && input >= 00) {
                if(input >= greatest)
                    greatest = input;

            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Error: Make sure the grade is between 0 and 100!\nEnter a new grade!");
            }
        }

        System.out.println("\nHighest grade: "+greatest);

    }
}
```

Comment: This does not output the highest grade statement

Comment: It's correctly working. I've tested it. Try now. I've added print statement before input.

Comment: See this: jdoodle.com/a/1ppy

Answer (score 1):

Scores array list is empty. You forgot to insert values inside array.

```
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
                 System.out.print("Enter a grade (between 0 and 100): ");
                  int temp = scan.nextInt();         
                if (input <= 100 && input >= 00) {
                  if( temp > greatest )
                      greatest = temp;
                 }
               else{
            System.out.println("Error: Make sure the grade is between 0 and 
                100!\nEnter a new grade!");
                } 
            }
```

Comment: `scores` is not an array

Comment: I get an error that states The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to ArrayList<Integer> @Pradeesh tet

Comment: use `scores.add(scan.nextInt());`

Comment: arraylist changed now.

Comment: Now it prints highest grade is -1

Comment: Again you getting input in while loop. You got to check the logic in while loop.

Comment: You are getting input in for loop. So i suggest Try to find max while getting the input in for loop. Don't store it in arraylist.

Comment: @Het parikh replace your for loop and while loop.

Comment: Replace it with what @Pradeeshtet

Comment: replace with above for loop

Answer (score 1):

This is not required two loops. In the for loop you just read values. so you can simply remove it. And try like this

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HighestGrade {

  public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner scan =  new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Integer> scores = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int greatest = -1;

    while (scores.size()<5) {
      System.out.print("Enter a grade (between 0 and 100): ");
      int input = scan.nextInt();
      if (input <= 100 && input >= 00) {
        scores.add(input);
        if(input >= greatest)
          greatest = input;

      }
      else{
        System.out.println("Error: Make sure the grade is between 0 and 100!\nEnter a new grade!");
      }
    }

    System.out.println("\nHighest grade: "+greatest);

  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

The problem seems to be here is you are not adding the input values to the ArrayList scores at the for loop. That means the fifth input only added to the list and considered. So for this piece of code the greatest value is not printed. Only having last value as the input.

```
for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
    System.out.print("Enter a grade (between 0 and 100): ");
    scores.add(scan.nextInt());
}
```

Comment: there are already two (better formatted) answers with the same solution.